# How to deploy changes of nodejs app to ALL AWS E2 instances (load balancer)?

Tags: node.js, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I have a NodeJs application.
Now app deployed through TeamCity on the single instance in the Amazon Cloud.
It should - raise the farm for the load balancer, and contain the current state of the application on those instances.
At the start of the instance - not a problem, I think just a script that will extort from GIT changes.

But when running instances, how to initialize (preferably with computation in teamcity) - download new files on the instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I am answering in right context. I would suggest you use some kind of Continuous Integration setup for this like Jenkins. So once you push your code to a cloud repository (Github, Gitlab, Bitbucket, etc) it is built and deployed on all the instances including the main server. So this is a kind of automation where you do a one time setup and you can monitor builds from a proper dashboard (in case of jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

- Create a snapshot of your existing instance.
- Create a new instance (and create a new volume by snapshot) after that attach it to newly created instance. This new volume should be `dev/sda`
- Restart the server on new machine.
- Create a load balancer and attach the both instance.